# how to properly pass prop from laravel 8 blade to vue 3 component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vuejs3

I'm trying to get the value of user prop as in the blade file when the App component is mounted but I get undefined in the console. I was wondering if something changed in `Vue 3` because it worked in `Vue 2`.

How can I get the value of the user prop?

**laravel.blade file**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <App 
    @if(auth()->check()) 
        :user="1"
    @endif> 
    </App>
@endsection
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div> {{user}} </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'App',

    props: [ 'user'],

    mounted(){
        console.log(this.user)
    }
}
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './components/App'
import router from './router';

require('./bootstrap'); 
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router).mount("#app")
```

Comment: You don't do it this way, you have to do an AJAX call to your Laravel and get any info you want. But if you still want to do it this way, I don't see any problem, I have no idea why it is an error to you. Try changing `<App></App>` to `<App />`

Comment: I need to get a dynamic value to send an ajax request from `<App />`

Answer (score 0):

---

From the migration docs:

*The propsData option has been removed. If you need to pass props to the root component instance during its creation, you should use the second argument of createApp*

```
const app = createApp(
  {
    props: ['username'],
    template: '<div>{{ username }}</div>'
  },
  { username: 'Evan' }
)
```

It's not as convenient as the Vue 2 way, and I haven't found a good work-around of sending data from your Laravel controller directly to your Vue component. Best bet may be to get the info by querying your API in the created() method in Vue.